# Postfix3 (3.5.7), file not found error

Tags: linux, postfix, redhat, smtp

I'm installing Postfix 3.5.7 on my SMTP server (on Linux CentOS) and then running `postfix set-permissions`. But that is leading to an error for a lot of files. I commented out few on initial errors however I see there are a lot of errors for that.

I saw `set-permissions` is using `/etc/postfix/postfix-files` which has a lot of files and the error could be there for many more files.

Also, postfix script is calling post-install script with `create-missing` parameter, however it is not creating, but failing with missing file error.

```
set-permissions|upgrade-configuration)
    $daemon_directory/post-install create-missing "$@"
    ;;
```

Did anyone face the same and is there a workaround/fix to this (if I have to stick with the same version)?.

Comment: Unclear whether you are seeing warning about optional files or about files that should be present. Whenever you ask about "errors".. quote them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just commented the files which were coming as error in the "Missing file/directory" error and after commenting few files in ( `/etc/postfix/postfix-files`), it worked well.